# How to Create JS Object from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a string whose value is (according to console.log()):

`j:{"address":"North Road 34 ","zip":"00002 ","state":"Texas ","city":"Dallas  ","country":"US"}`

I dont know why it starts with that letter 'j', but i am only interested in what is inside it. 
I have tried JSON.parse() but throws an error: 'unexpected token: 'j'.

The eval() solution doesn't seems to work either , it throws 'unexpected token: ':'

Thank You!

Comment: Where did that string come from? By itself, it's obviously not a valid json string.  Just remove the `j:` part...

Comment: @RobG That sounds good. how would you take out that 'J:'  ?

Comment: If mentioned string is constant, then you can simply alter it. If its coming from some external source. you can use 'substring()' or even apply regex to it. Another option var ns = JSON.parse("{" + actualString + "}");

Answer (score 3):

Well... the only explanation is that it shouldn't start with `j:` since it's invalid JSON, but it does (probably because of a bug).

You can easily fix your string to make it valid by removing the invalid prefix from the JSON string.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourString.replace(/^j:/, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like plalx's answer but leading junk isn't hard coded:

```
var s = 'j:{"address":"North Road 34 ","zip":"00002 ","state":"Texas ","city":"Dallas  ","country":"US"} ';

// Strip everything up to leading "{":
var obj = JSON.parse(s.substring(s.indexOf('{')));
```

Comment: The leading junk could in theory contain a `{`, so the solution is still not generic. The only generic solution would be to try to parse the input starting at every character until the end, but that would be silly.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the don't-know-where-come-from `j:` and then `JSON.parse()` will work. Show more code if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick.

```
var v="j:{"address":"North Road 34 ","zip":"00002 ","state":"Texas ","city":"Dallas  ","country":"US"}"

var rpVal=v.replace("j:","");

var yourObject=new someObject();

yourObject= eval("(" + rpVal+ ")");
```

This way you will achieve your goal easily.